# How to add legends in this context?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, kaggle

[image: Highest yearly value]

```
songs %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(count=nth(pop,1))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(year),y=count,fill=year))+geom_bar(stat ='identity' )+theme_classic()
```

1.How can I adjust my legends to show years(2010:2019) rather than what it is showing right now?
2.Scale_size_manual is not working.

Comment: Since you mapped `year` to `fill`, you want `scale_fill_manual()` and not `scale_size_manual()`.  If `year` should be discrete instead of numeric you can use `fill = factor(year)`.

Comment: @aosmith  Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length,hence it does not work!!

Comment: You likely want `scale_fill_gradient()` and `breaks` if you continue to work with a numeric `fill`.  You should add code you've attempted along with errors to your question so folks can see how your code "does not work".  It will also help to have a reproducible example; I don't know where `songs` comes from, maybe it is built on the `billboard` dataset?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `year` as a factor each time (or externally), not just once. I don't have your data, so I'll use `mtcars`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# first plot
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(carb), disp, fill=carb)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

# second plot
mutate(mtcars, carb = factor(carb)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carb, disp, fill=carb)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

# alternate code for second plot, not shown
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(carb), disp, fill=factor(carb))) +
  # both     ^^^^^^        and        ^^^^^^
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: two ggplots]

(There are numerous ways to convert to a factor. I'm using `dplyr` here, but it can easily be done in base or `data.table`.)

I included the "alternate" code above that shows the manual `factor` being applied to each use of `carb`; this is not the preferred method in my mind, since if you're doing it multiple times, just do it once before the plotting and use it multiple times. If you need both the ordinal `year` and the numeric version, you can add a new field, such as `ordinal_year=factor(year)`.